# Azure App - Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: Azure CLI not installed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a console app that I am deploying to Azure App Services. The app runs fine when running on my local computer, but when I publish it to Azure, I get the following error:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.922.41905
.NET Version: 6.0.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: Azure CLI not installed
   at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.RequestCliAccessTokenAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](ValueTask`1 task)
   at Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential.GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   ...
```

The code for accessing the key vault look like this:

```
AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration = new AuthenticationConfiguration();
            _configuration.Bind("Authentication", authenticationConfiguration);

SecretClient keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(
                new Uri(_configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUri")),
                new DefaultAzureCredential());
            authenticationConfiguration.AccessTokenSecret = keyVaultClient.GetSecret("access-token-secret").Value.Value;

services.AddSingleton(authenticationConfiguration);
```

How do I install Azure CLI in Azure Web Service (or how do I properly access the key vault in my Console App)?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing the app as Self-Contained fixed the problem.